# Getting odd results with a method for getting point inside triangle

Tags: java, opengl, math, lwjgl

i am using a method i found on the internet that was in cpp and i changed it a bit for java. it seems to work only half the time. is it a bug with java? because it will return true or false depending on where you are inside the triangle. can anybody help me fix it or find a better way to test for a point inside a triangle? heres the method. sorry if its hard to understand the question

```
    public static float area(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3)
{
   return (float) Math.abs((x1*(y2-y3) + x2*(y3-y1)+ x3*(y1-y2))/2.0);
}

/* A function to check whether point P(x, y) lies inside the triangle formed 
   by A(x1, y1), B(x2, y2) and C(x3, y3) */
public static boolean isInside(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3, float x, float y)
{   
   /* Calculate area of triangle ABC */
   float A = area (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

   /* Calculate area of triangle PBC */  
   float A1 = area (x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);

   /* Calculate area of triangle PAC */  
   float A2 = area (x1, y1, x, y, x3, y3);

   /* Calculate area of triangle PAB */   
   float A3 = area (x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y);

   /* Check if sum of A1, A2 and A3 is same as A */
   return (A == A1 + A2 + A3);
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, I actually question the validity of that method, just looking at it, it checks to see if a point is within the triangle based off of the area's of that point to each other point of the triangle. I don't like that logic because that could fail in certain situations. Do you need help coming up with a new one?

Comment: Could you post some examples of when the method gave correct and incorrect output? That would help us out a lot more

Comment: i could make a quick video...

Comment: Not my preferred method, but shoot, go for it

Comment: http://youtu.be/iv7BKaq9x-U heres a vid

Comment: btw if you have another method i would love to see it. especially if it works for 3 dimensional triangles :P

Comment: I would but the answer given a few seconds ago seems to solve it quite well

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of floating point precision. Keep in mind that floating point calculations are executed with a limited amount of precision. Therefore, if you make different calculations that mathematically should produce the same result, the actual result produced by your computer will generally not be identical.

The problem is therefore with this test:

```
return (A == A1 + A2 + A3);
```

If the point is inside the triangle, `A` and `A1 + A2 + A3` will have very similar values, but not necessarily identical values due to limited floating point precision during the calculation.

The most direct way to fix it would be to allow for some imprecision in the comparison:

```
return Math.abs(A - (A1 + A2 + A3) < eps);
```

where `eps` is a small floating point constant. Choosing a good value for these kinds of tolerances is always tricky, so it's best to avoid algorithms that make this necessary if anyway possible (see proposed solution below). If you make the tolerance too small, the test will fail for points inside the triangle. If you make it too large, you will allow for more false positives, because points just slightly outside the triangle will pass the test.

If you really wanted to use this kind of test, it would be more stable to test for the relative difference instead of the absolute difference, since the absolute error will typically increase as the values themselves get larger. Testing the relative difference would look like this:

```
return Math.abs((A - A1 - A2 - A3) / A) < eps;
```

Then for the value of `eps`, I would start with something that is safely larger than the relative precision of a `float` value, which is about 7 digits. Something like `1.0e-5f` seems reasonable.

There are better ways of doing a "point in triangle" test. Actually, I think you could use most of the math you already have. I haven't tested the following at all, so it comes without any warranty, but I believe it should work.

The idea is that you don't really need to care that all the partial areas sum up to the area of the triangle. I believe it's sufficient that they are all positive. You can change the `area` function to return the *signed* area by removing the `abs()` call:

```
public static float area(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3)
{
    return 0.5f * (x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2));
}
```

Then calculate `A1`, `A2` and `A3` as before, and check that they are all positive:

```
return A1 >= 0.0f && A2 >= 0.0f && A3 >= 0.0f;
```

This assumes that the triangle has counter-clockwise orientation. If you want it to also work for clockwise orientation, you would need to check that all three values have the same sign.

Comment: Very well said, I would also add that the amount of precision is also important when calculating this out. He showed a video demonstrating the use of the program and it is meant to be inside of a 3d plane (geometric, not aeronautics). Small discrepancies may need to be managed to a certain degree. Here is the link the the video http://youtu.be/iv7BKaq9x-U

Comment: im not familiar with floating point constants, but i giuess you want me to replace the return (A == A1 + A2 + A3); with something simalar to return Math.abs(A - (A1 + A2 + A3) < 0.1); ?

Comment: durdurdur i think this is working.
    return Math.abs(A - (A1 + A2 + A3)) < 0.1;
thanks!

Comment: I added some more detail about how exactly you would do this test. But I would really recommend that you use an approach that doesn't need this, like the one I added to the answer (if it works...).